# undefined symbols for structs on compile MPLab XC8 on pic16F872

Tags: xc8, pic16f

I'm receiving the undefined symbols error on XC8 for two struct arrays declared as externs in file io.h. Why is this happening?

```
    #ifndef _IO_H_
    #define _IO_H_
```

```
#include <pic16f872.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "../var.h"


#define DEBOUNCE_LOW        50000
#define DEBOUNCE_HIGH       50000
#define DEBOUNCE_HOLD       4000000

#define TOTAL_INPUTS        3



typedef struct {
   unsigned char press : 1;
    unsigned char hold  : 1;        
} Input;


typedef struct {
    unsigned int low;
    unsigned int high;  
    unsigned long hold;
} Debounce;


extern Input input[TOTAL_INPUTS];   //<== The variables declaration
extern Debounce debounce[TOTAL_INPUTS];  // <==


#define BT_UP           input[0]
#define BT_DOWN         input[1]


#define BT_UP_PIN       PORTCbits.RC1
#define BT_DOWN_PIN     PORTCbits.RC3

#define LED1            PORTBbits.RB1
#define LED2            PORTBbits.RB2



void setupIo( void );
void initIo( void );
void resetIo( char input );
void taskIo( void );
void readIo( void );
void writeIo( void );

#endif // _IO_H_
```

and the io.c:

```
  #include "io.h";

void initIo( void ){
    for( int in = 0; in < TOTAL_INPUTS; in++ ){        
        input[in].hold = false;
        input[in].press = false;
        resetIo( in );
    }
}
```

void resetIo( unsigned char input){
        debounce[input].low = DEBOUNCE_LOW;
        debounce[input].high = DEBOUNCE_HIGH;
        debounce[input].hold = DEBOUNCE_HOLD;
}

void taskIo( void ){

```
if( !BT_UP_PIN ){  //botão up pressionado

    if( debounce[0].low > 0) debounce[0].low--;
    if( !debounce[0].low ){

        if( debounce[0].hold > 0 ) debounce[0].hold--;            
        if( !debounce[0].hold){                
            input[0].hold = true;
        }
    }
} else if( !debounce[0].low ){ // botão solto

    if( debounce[0].high > 0) debounce[0].high--;

    if( !debounce[0].high ){
        input[0].press = true;
        resetIo( 0 );            
    }
}

if( !BT_DOWN_PIN ){  //botão up pressionado

    if( debounce[1].low > 0) debounce[1].low--;
    if( !debounce[1].low ){

        if( debounce[0].hold > 0 ) debounce[0].hold--;           
        if( !debounce[1].hold){                
            input[1].hold = true;
        }
    }
} else if( !debounce[1].low ){ // botão solto

    if( debounce[1].high > 0) debounce[1].high--;

    if( !debounce[1].high ){
        input[1].press = true;
        resetIo( 1 );            
    }
}
```

}

compiler error:

```
    CLEAN SUCCESSFUL (total time: 125ms)
make -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make1: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/Microchip/Fonte Chaveada/FonteChaveada.X'
make  -f nbproject/Makefile-default.mk dist/default/production/FonteChaveada.X.production.hex
make2: Entering directory 'C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/Microchip/Fonte Chaveada/FonteChaveada.X'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.41\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=16F872 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=0 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,+osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/main.p1  main.c 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.41\bin\xc8.exe" --pass1  --chip=16F872 -Q -G  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=0 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,+osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib   --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"    -obuild/default/production/drivers/io/io.p1  drivers/io/io.c 
hw_config.h:22: warning: (162) #warning: "Sistema configurado como DEBUG!"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microchip\xc8\v1.41\bin\xc8.exe"  --chip=16F872 -G -mdist/default/production/FonteChaveada.X.production.map  --double=24 --float=24 --opt=+asm,+asmfile,-speed,+space,-debug,-local --addrqual=ignore --mode=free -P -N255 --warn=0 --asmlist -DXPRJ_default=default  --summary=default,-psect,-class,+mem,-hex,-file --output=default,-inhx032 --runtime=default,+clear,+init,-keep,-no_startup,+osccal,-resetbits,-download,-stackcall,+clib --output=-mcof,+elf:multilocs --stack=compiled:auto:auto "--errformat=%f:%l: error: (%n) %s" "--warnformat=%f:%l: warning: (%n) %s" "--msgformat=%f:%l: advisory: (%n) %s"      --memorysummary dist/default/production/memoryfile.xml -odist/default/production/FonteChaveada.X.production.elf  build/default/production/main.p1 build/default/production/drivers/io/io.p1

Microchip MPLAB XC8 C Compiler (Free Mode) V1.41
Build date: Jan 24 2017
Part Support Version: 1.41
Copyright (C) 2017 Microchip Technology Inc.
License type: Node Configuration
```

:: warning: (1273) Omniscient Code Generation not available in Free mode
main.c:88: warning: (764) mismatched comparison
:0: error: (500) undefined symbols:
    _debounce(dist/default/production\FonteChaveada.X.production.obj) _input(dist/default/production\FonteChaveada.X.production.obj) 
(908) exit status = 1
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:141: recipe for target 'dist/default/production/FonteChaveada.X.production.hex' failed
make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H6EO.png): Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/Microchip/Fonte Chaveada/FonteChaveada.X'
nbproject/Makefile-default.mk:84: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJOfK.png): Leaving directory 'C:/Users/User/Google Drive/Desenvolvimento/Projetos/Microchip/Fonte Chaveada/FonteChaveada.X'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6H6EO.png): *** [dist/default/production/FonteChaveada.X.production.hex] Error 1
make[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJOfK.png): *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)

and my main.c file as well:

```
#include "hw_config.h";
```

/*=====================================================================================*\
 =======                        INTERRUPÇÔES                                   =========
*=====================================================================================*/

void interrupt interruptFuction( void ){
    if( INTCONbits.T0IF ){
        INTCONbits.T0IF = 0;

```
    return;
}

if( PIR1bits.TMR2IF ){
    PIR1bits.TMR2IF = 0;

    return;
}
```

}

void main( void ){

```
int pwm = 0;

initHw();


while( true ){
    LED1 = ~LED1;

    taskIo();

    if( BT_UP.press ){  // input.press
        if( pwm < PWM_MAX ) pwm++;
        CCPR1L = (char) pwm;
        CCPR1H = pwm >> 8;
        LED2 = ~LED2;
    }

    if( BT_DOWN.press ){
        if( pwm >= 1 ) pwm--;
        CCPR1L = (char) pwm;
        CCPR1H = pwm >> 8;
        LED2 = ~LED2;
    }

} //end while
```

} //end main

void initHw( void ){

/*=====================================================================================*\
 =======                    SETUP SFFRs                                        =========
*=====================================================================================*/
    ADCON0 = 0b00000000; // Desalibilita pull-ups ou ADC não lembro
    ADCON1 = 0b00000111;
    OPTION_REG = 0b10000011;
    INTCON = 0b10100000; //Habilita interrupções
//    T1CON = 0b10000000; //Habilita e configura Timer 1
    PIE1 = 0b00000110; // Habilita CCPIE e TMR2IE inerrupts para PWM
    T2CON = 0b00000100; //Habilita e configura Timer 2 (1:1)
    PR2 = 5;
    /*  Para PWM é utilizável somente o preScaler (bits 1-0):
     * 00= 1:1;
     * 01=1:4;
     * 1x=1:16;
     */
    CCP1CON = 0b00001111; //Habilita PWM
    CCPR1H = 0b0000000; //Ciclo alto do Duty do PWM
    CCPR1L = 0b00000000; //Ciclo baixo do Duty do PWM

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      Limpeza dos SFRs.
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
TMR0 = 0;
TMR2 = 0;


/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      Limpeza dos PORTS e LATS.
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
PORTA = 0;
PORTB = 0;
PORTC = 0;

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *      Configuração da direção dos pinos de I/O's.
 *-------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//        76543210
TRISA = 0b11111111; //entrada
TRISB = 0b11111001; //saída
TRISC = 0b00001010; //saída
```

}

I've tried to mark de Xc8 Linker option buts its not enabled for this device.

[image: Project Properties]

[image]

Comment: Please fix the code formatting, otherwise some characters might be missing and we can't tell if it is relevant to your problem!

Comment: Seems the compiler cannot find the arrays `debounce[]` and `input[]`. Where are these defined?

Comment: Sorry about the formating, i'm trying to fix. 

the arrays are declareted in io.h as extern Structs arrays. So hw_config.h import the io.h and then my file main.c import the hw_config.h.

Comment: Declaring a var as extern tells the compiler "Hey, these variables exist somewhere, dont worry about where they are located".
When its time for the linker to run, it sees this extern flag and says "Ok, which one of you has the actual variable so I can give it to the rest of the people who asked for it". If nobody has the actual instantiation, you get this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a difference between **declaring** a variable and **defining** it. You've **declared** that `debounce[]` and `input[]` exist somewhere else by using the `extern` keyword, but you've not actually **defined** them anywhere (at least that we can see from the code provided).

To simply fix the error, you can define the arrays in your io.c file. But as far as I can tell, `debounce[]` and `input[]` are not used anywhere else in your program, so there's no need to expose them in the header file (i.e. define them in the io.c file and remove the `extern` declarations from the io.h file).